# Set date with milliseconds from epoch

Tags: date

How do I set the `date` using milliseconds and or seconds from epoch?

`date -s 127846398127`?

Answer (score 2):

```
date -s @127846398127
```

should do it... (But just with seconds, so I'd expect a 10-digit value.)

Answer (score 0):

You need a dot `.` separator between seconds and nanos.

```
date -s @1611850626.716999059
```